# Oracle Foreign or Primary keys

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, ddl, primary-key-design

I'm a bit confused over when I should use a primary or foreign key. I have two tables, and in both of them, some of the columns reference columns that are primary keys in other tables.
Here they are:

```
CREATE TABLE roles (
movie_id NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL REFERENCES movies(movie_id),
actor_id NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL REFERENCES actors(actor_id),
movie_description VARCHAR2(50),
salary NUMBER(10),
CONSTRAINT pk_roles PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, actor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE profits (
movie_id NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
gross_profit NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
net_profit NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_profits FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(movie_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

In the first table I have made a composite primary key from teh two columns that reference columns in other tables. Those columns happen to be primary keys in their respective tables.

In the second table, I've made a foreign key again referencing a primary key in anther table. But what is best practice? Should the key in the first table also be a foreign key since it references primary keys in other tables?

Answer (score 1):

Primary key constraints and unique constraints prevent duplicate rows. Duplicate rows not only waste space, they make it harder to get meaningful answers from your database.

Foreign key constraints restrict values to those that exist in another table. The target of a foreign key constraint is commonly a primary key, but it could be any column(s) that have a unique constraint.

Every table should have a primary key constraint. If the column(s) that make up the primary key also require a foreign key constraint, add the foreign key constraint as well.

Your table "roles" is fine, as far as implementing primary key constraints and foreign key constraints. But "profits" needs a primary key.

Comment: So foreign key constraints are additional to primary key constraints, and restrict values to those found in the foreign columns? Does this make the "...REFERENCES ..." statements in "roles" defunct then, as I'm not creating a foreign key there?

Comment: You're creating two foreign key constraints in "roles". In `movie_id ... REFERENCES movies(movie_id)`, you require the movie to exist before you store information about the roles actors played in that movie. In `actor_id ... REFERENCES actors(actor_id)`, you require the actor to exist before you store information about the movies that actor played in. Both those foreign key constraints make perfectly good sense.

Comment: What would be the difference between how I have the profits table above and doing `movie_id NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL REFERENCES movies(movie_id)` and a constraint like `CONSTRAINT pk_profits PRIMARY KEY (movie_id)`?

Comment: As it is, the "profits" table allows duplicate rows. A primary key constraint prevents that particular kind of nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

To your Question "Should the key in the first table also be a foreign key since it references primary keys in other tables?"

There is no simple answer, as it heavily depends on type of planned usage of data and database being used. If you need a simple answer, yes it is a good idea. Below is the longer version.

Pros :

- It helps keep your data clean.
- Based on how database is planned to be used and which database you are using, some databases, tend to optimize joins better, if Foreign keys are defined for joins upfront.

Cons :

- If you plan to bulk load into your tables frequently, then FK constraints tend to slow down your loads, if that is the case, some databases allow you to define soft constraints, which are only used for query optimization purposes, but are not verified during loads.